# Gram Schmidt For $R_2[x]$ Basis

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Find an orthonormal basis for $R_2[x]$ where $\langle f(x),g(x)\rangle=\int_0^1
f(x)g(x)\,dx$

I started with $\{1,x,x^2\}$

$$\|v_1\|=\sqrt{\langle v_1,v_1\rangle}=\int_0^1\ dx=\sqrt{1}=1$$

So $e_1=1$

$$v'_2=v_2-\langle v_2,e_1\rangle e_1=x-\int_0^1x\ dx=x-\frac{1}{2}$$

$$\|v_2\|=\sqrt{\langle v_2,v_2\rangle}=\sqrt{\int_0^1 (x-\frac{1}{2})^2\ dx}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{12}}$$

$$e_2=\sqrt{12}(x-\frac{1}{2})$$

\begin{align}
v'_3=v_3-\langle v_3,e_1\rangle e_1-\langle v_3,e_2\rangle e_2 & =x^2-\int_0^1 x^2\ dx-12\int_0^1(x^4-\frac{x^3}{2}\ dx)(x-\frac{1}{2}) \\[10pt]
&=x^2-\frac{9}{10}x+\frac{7}{60}
\end{align}

which seems to be wrong as $e_3=\sqrt{180}(x^2-x+\frac{1}{6})$

Comment: Proper MathJax usage is $\langle v_1,v_2\rangle,$ not $<v_1,v_2>. \qquad$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your functions $e_1$ and $e_2$ are correct, but you made a mistake in the computation of $v_3'(x)$. You should have obtained$$v_3'(x)=x^2-x+\frac16.$$And, since $\|v_3'\|=\frac1{6\sqrt5}$, $e_3(x)=6\sqrt5\left(x^2-x+\frac16\right)$.